# How make add_custom_target runs only on "make", NOT! in "make install"

Tags: cmake

This is my code:

```
add_custom_target (ts2qm)
file (GLOB _TS_FILES "*.ts")
foreach (_TS_FILE ${_TS_FILES})
    # ...
    add_custom_command(TARGET ts2qm POST_BUILD COMMAND "runme")
    # ...
endforeach (_TS_FILE ${_TS_FILES})

add_dependencies(../${PACKAGE} ts2qm)
```

So when i hit "make" this target is triggered as expected, but...is also triggered during "make install"....question here is: How to avoid triggered in "make install"?

Thanks.

/edit1:

```
file (GLOB _TS_FILES "*.ts")
foreach (_TS_FILE ${_TS_FILES})
# ...
add_custom_command(OUTPUT locales.txt COMMAND "runme" )
# ...
endforeach (_TS_FILE ${_TS_FILES})

add_custom_target (locales DEPENDS locales.txt)
add_dependencies(../${PACKAGE} locales)
```

with the same results :(

Comment: Does it make sense? You need `POST_BUILD` step to create a target. When you installing target, you also need to create target before install. If target can be created without `POST_BUILD` step why do you need it at all?

Answer (score 0):

The target "install" depends on the target "all", therefore you cannot avoid it using target-level dependencies.

The `add_custom_command(TARGET)` command runs every time that target should be run. You can try using `add_custom_command(OUTPUT)` that sets file-level dependencies, and therefore runs the command only when the .ts file is modified.